# Equivalent UWP BitMapEncoder in Xamarin / Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a (hopefully) simple question (I don’t have found an answer in Google)

I need an equivalent in Xamarin to UWP BitMapEncoder but I can't found it.

Thanks to all of you.

Regards.

Comment: What are you looking to do? Encode an image to PNG/JPG? Or?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit` library available, which does some basic image editing tasks on iOS and Android, but UWP is not yet supported unfortunately.

Otherwise it largely depends on your requirements. Processing images is built-in to each platform in some way, so your best bet would be to use the native approach by implementing a [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/). This allows you to create a platform-agnostic interface, that you will implement on each platform in a platform-specific manner. Then you can access the dependency service implementation using service locator pattern. Everything is described in detail in the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/).